# Bit manipulation in a range

Tags: bit-manipulation, bit

While I know the process to set/unset a bit at a specific location - what is the most efficient way to do this operation over a range (say from position x to y)?

```
101011011011

n=12
x=3,y=7(from right)

Bit set: 101011111111
Bit unset: 101010000011
```

The mask has to be pushed dynamically as x and y will obviously be random.
Thanks for the help.

Comment: Bit set over range - use `or` with mask.  Bit clear over range use `and` with mask.  Usually, the computer can do an entire range in 1 operation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are we talking about C-like operations? If you want `x` and `y` to be variables, you can build two masks:

```
unsigned set(unsigned val, int x, int y) {
  unsigned hi = ~0 << x;    // 1's at position x and higher
  unsigned lo = ~(~0 << y); // 1's at positions lower than y
  return val | (lo & hi);
}
```

and

```
unsigned clear(unsigned val, int x, int y) {
  unsigned hi = ~(~0 << x);   
  unsigned lo = ~0 << y; 
  return val & (lo | hi);
}
```

Note the end of the range is non-inclusive at the high end. So `set(foo, 5, 9)` sets bits 5 through 8, where each bit `i` is the one with value `2^i`.

Comment: Is this correct?From eamples - it seems to set the bits outside x and y range too

Comment: @IUnknown Thanks. I had the final operations wrong. Fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

To follow up
to set from 3 to 7:

```
value = 1010110...
mask = 0x7C; // 0111 1100 binary
value |= mask;
```

to clear

```
value = 1010110...
mask = 0x7C; // 0111 1100 binary
value &= ~mask;
```

using C style above where | is or, & is and, and ~ is compliment.

Comment: Please check the edit above - probably it was not clear at the outset

Answer (score 0):

If you count bits from 0 as usual, you can use:

```
unsigned set(unsigned x, unsigned l, unsigned h) {
    return x | (((1u << h) << 1) - (1u << l));
}

unsigned reset(unsigned x, unsigned l, unsigned h) {
    return x & ~(((1u << h) << 1) - (1u << l));
}
```